# How does Typescript make the type of a function parameter in an object depend on the value of another key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

### Column Interface

```
interface Column<T = any, P = keyof T | string> {
  dataIndex: P;
  render?: (value: P extends keyof T ? T[P] : any) => any
}
```

Let the type of render value satisfy:

1. When the value of dataIndex belongs to the key of T, the type of value is equal to type of T[dataIndex value]
2. When the value of dataIndex does not belong to the key of T, the type of value is equal to any

### Example

```
const dataSource = [{
  a: 1,
  b: '2'
}, ...]

const c: Column<(typeof dataSource)[0]> = [
  {
    dataIndex: 'a',
    render(value) {
      // the value expected to be number
    }
  },
  {
    dataIndex: 'b',
    render(value) {
      // the value expected to be string
    }
  },
  {
    dataIndex: 'c',
    render(value) {
      // the value expected to be any
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: I don't think this can be a type alias, but it does work with a function https://tsplay.dev/mxj4Kw Is that an answer you would accept?

Comment: @AlexWayne I know this function based approach, but it's not ideal. Want to wait for other answers. Thanks

Comment: There is no specific `Column<T>` type you can write which works the way you want with type inference; see [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/mbEg3N) for details. Either you force `dataIndex` to be `keyof T` in which case your type will be a discriminated union and you get nice behavior (except for disallowed `"c"` etc), *or* you allow it to be any `string` in which case the compiler can't distinguish between the `any` case and the `T[P]` case (there are no negated types like `string & not keyof T`). You should probably accept the function-based approach or relax your constraints somehow.

Comment: ...so how should we proceed here?